# How do I delete rows that contain a specific string unless they contain another string in R?

Tags: r

I'm using a df with the following structure:

```
A <- c(1:3)
B <- c("Sweet", "Home", "Sweet Home")
df <- data.frame(A,B)
```

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sweet |
| 2 | Home |
| 3 | Sweet Home |

I want to be able to drop all the rows that contain the word "Sweet", unless they contain the word "Home".
I have been using the following code:`df1 <- df[!grepl("Sweet", df$B),]` but this deletes both rows 1 and 3, like so:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Home |

How can I do this so I can keep the values where Sweet has Home in it, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways using binary logic. The second is an application of de Morgan's laws.

```r
A <- c(1:3)
B <- c("Sweet", "Home", "Sweet Home")
df <- data.frame(A,B)

i <- grepl("sweet", df$B, ignore.case = TRUE)
j <- grepl("home", df$B, ignore.case = TRUE)

df[!(i & !j), ]
#>   A          B
#> 2 2       Home
#> 3 3 Sweet Home

df[!i | j, ]
#>   A          B
#> 2 2       Home
#> 3 3 Sweet Home
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

If you have one word to drop unless a list of words is present, the function below might be what you want. The `words` vector must have the unwanted word first, followed by the other, wanted words.

```r
# X is the input data.frame 
# col is the column to search for
specialfilter <- function(X, col, words) {
  l <- lapply(words, \(w) grepl(w, X[[col]], ignore.case = TRUE))
  l[[1]] <- !l[[1]]
  i <- Reduce(`|`, l)
  X[i, ]
}

specialfilter(df, "B", c("sweet", "home"))
#>   A          B
#> 2 2       Home
#> 3 3 Sweet Home
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Is there a way to automate it and make it more efficient so I don't have to define multiple conditions individually?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% filter(!str_detect(B, '^Sweet$'))
  A          B
1 2       Home
2 3 Sweet Home
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a extension of your code to filter out `Sweet` and keeping if row contains `Home`:

```
df[-c(grepl("Sweet", df$B)&!grepl("Home", df$B)), ]

  A          B
2 2       Home
3 3 Sweet Home
```